# PHP - Initialize instance of object within a constructor of a class, access within a static member

Tags: php, controller, static-methods

I am using a framework to route my routes to controllers and their respective methods, however I am not sure how to initialize classes within the constructor and then access this via a static member of the same class.

```
class Controller {

    static private $test = null;

    private function __construct(){

        #$this->test = new Test();
        self::$test = new Test();

    }

    public static function Index(){

        // rather than this
        #$test = new Test();
        #echo $test->greet();

        // something like this
        #echo self::$test->greet();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize controller first. You can call `new Controller();` for this which then puts an instance of `Test` in `private $test`

```
<?php
Class Test {

    public function greet(){
        return "hello world";   
    }

}

class Controller {

    static private $test = null;

    private function __construct(){

        self::$test = new Test();

    }

    public static function Index(){

        new Controller();
        echo self::$test->greet();

    }

}

Controller::Index(); //Returns hello world
```

Comment: I don't think I am able to do this as the framework which I am using routes to a controller's method rather than initializing it this way. App::route('/', array('\Prj\Controller', 'Index')); Is the only method to access the constructor properties by calling the class itself within the static method?

Comment: If I'm correct you're calling the `Index` method from controller in the route? Then it should work.

Comment: What framework are you using? It can be possible to make framework instantiate class when hitting route. Then no need to do any workaround like this.

Comment: @mhvvzmak1 I thought so :) check this issue: https://github.com/mikecao/flight/issues/245#issuecomment-194983785 hope it'll give some light on how it should be done.

Comment: Hi, I got issue with this: Call to private Prj\Controller\Index::__construct() from invalid context (0), construct has to be public only, no private?

Comment: @mhvvzmak1 yes `__construct` should be public.